# How do I make this plugin return false and still chain

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have written a plugin which isn't finished yet I might add. All it does at the moment is to check if all inputs are empty. If any inputs are empty it puts a message under the input.

Now the plugin is suppose to return false if it fails.

The problem is chaining. The way it works at the moment it doesn't chain if I return false, because I am not returning base.

How do I make this plugin return false and still chain.

```
;(function($){
"use strict";
$.fn.valiDate = function(options){      

    var base=this;
    /*Adds the input on the page */
    if(!$('#asi_validate').length)
    {
        $('.footer').before('<span style="border:1px solid black;background-color:#FFF;color:red;\
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888888;padding:5px;position:absolute;width:auto;display:none;\
        " id="asi_validate"></span>');
    }

        var valid = true;
        var validatepos=$('#asi_validate');

    base.check_key= function(){
        $(this).keyup(function(){
            validatepos.fadeOut(50);
        }); 

    }       

    base.check= function() {
        $('input').each(function() {

            if (this.value == '') {
                var cell=$(this);
                var position = cell.offset(),maxLength=cell.val().length;
                validatepos.css('left',position.left),
                validatepos.css('top',position.top+(cell.outerHeight()+2)),
                validatepos.fadeIn(100),
                validatepos.html('This field is required');
                valid = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
    }


    base.check_key();
    base.check();

        if (valid === false) {
            return false;
        }
    return base;
};
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: That’s impossible. It either returns the current jQuery object, so that further chained method calls are possible, or it returns false. You can not return more than one value. You need to decide whether you need chain-ability, _or_ a return value that indicates some sort of status. Both at the same time makes no sense.

Comment: Perhaps I need to use a callback instead then. Will investigate. Thanks for your input